# How to check how the table structure effects the performance of my query

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to check how the table structure of a certain table effects the performance of a delete query.

This is not a generalised question, I have a table, with currently 2.2 million records approximately, i want to run delete query, I want to see how InnoDB stores data, in my disk, so i can change the structure of the table.

Is there any tool or command to check the structure of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `chat_server` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `number_of_clans` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `weight` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

DELETE QUERY

```
DELETE c FROM `chat_history` c inner join ( select message_id from `chat_history` where     clan_id=1005 ORDER BY message_id DESC limit 30, 30000  ) x where c.`message_id` <= x.`message_id` AND c.clan_id = 1005
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the table structure with SHOW CREATE TABLE `tblname\G`. Also, please show the DELETE query itself.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**Procedure Analyse** will be helpful command: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/procedure-analyse.html

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_name`
PROCEDURE ANALYSE ( )
```